# Return value with logic operators

Tags: c, recursion, return-value, logical-operators

Can anyone explain to me how this return works when there are logic operators? Also explain when this function is going to return itself and the array elements?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int consecutive_3(int x, int y, int z, int a[], int n)
{
    if(n<3)
       return 0;
    return ((a[n-3] == x) && (a[n-2] == y) && (a[n-1] == z)) || consecutive_3(x, y, z, a, n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be the same

```
int consecutive_3(int x, int y, int z, int a[], int n)
{
    if (n < 3)
       return 0;

    if ((a[n-3] == x) && (a[n-2] == y) && (a[n-1] == z))
       return 1;

    return consecutive_3(x, y, z, a, n - 1);
}
```

notice: c evaluates logical expressions from left to right and `&&` has a [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) (is evaluatet first) than `||`.

Comment: Except the last `return` needs a `!= 0` or `? 1 : 0` or something.

Comment: @aschepler why? `consecutive_3` is already returning either 0 or 1

Comment: Fair point. I was thinking more of the exact equivalence by expression/statement, not the particular context.

Answer (score 1):

> how does return works in this case when there is logic operator

There is nothing special about `return` - it simply returns the value of the expression once it has been evalutaed.

So in your case:

```
return ((a[n-3] == x) && (a[n-2] == y) && (a[n-1] == z)) || consecutive_3(x, y, z, a, n-1);
```

is just the same as

```
int temp = ((a[n-3] == x) && (a[n-2] == y) && (a[n-1] == z)) || consecutive_3(x, y, z, a, n-1);
return temp;
```

> when this function is going to return itself and when array elements

It never does any of those. It always returns an integer.

The idea seems to be that the function looks through an array to find 3 conseqcutive elements with the value `x`, `y` and `z`.

If found it returns 1.

If not found it calls itself but looks at a new point in the array, i.e. next lower array index. This continues until the whole array has been searched.

If still not found it returns 0. That is what the `if (n < 3) return 0;` is for.

So assume the array:

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

and the function call

```
consecutive_3(1, 2, 3, a, 6);
```

Then you have like this

```
 Is 1, 2, 3 equal 4, 5, 6 No, so call again
 Is 1, 2, 3 equal 3, 4, 5 No, so call again
 Is 1, 2, 3 equal 2, 3, 4 No, so call again
 Is 1, 2, 3 equal 1, 2, 3 Yes, return 1
```

Had the call been

```
consecutive_3(10, 2, 3, a, 6);
```

it would be

```
 Is 10, 2, 3 equal 4, 5, 6 No, so call again
 Is 10, 2, 3 equal 3, 4, 5 No, so call again
 Is 10, 2, 3 equal 2, 3, 4 No, so call again
 Is 10, 2, 3 equal 1, 2, 3 No, so call again
 No more unchecked elements so return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This function checks whether there are 3 consecutive numbers x y z in the array a[] from index 0 to n-1. It returns 0 (not found) or 1 (found).

First, an out-of-range check is done:

```
if (n < 3)
   return 0;  // there are less than 3, can not match
```

Then, tests the last three numbers:

```
return ((a[n-3] == x) && (a[n-2] == y) && (a[n-1] == z)) (|| ...)
```

if all three match, it returns 1 as value. But if not, it returns the right part of the expression after || (logical or).

That part calls again the same function, but shortening the array, so it tests the last 3 again of the shortened array.

The key to understand this is that the *return* chooses between two compatible alternatives (both are a boolean value); the first is the intended (but partial) test, the second is the intended test performed on different data, only if the first fails.

It is a clever system, but not very fast because of the overhead of calling itself again and again, stressing the stack and passing arguments; a single *for* loop would have been simple the same, and much faster.